# Python Zip Code

Tags: python, regex, zipcode

I am very new to Python and struggling to execute what I need.
I need to extract Zip codes out of the string "concat".
I was researching regex, but I am struggling on the functionality.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from pandas import ExcelWriter
```

I imported the CSV, encoded text type of upload issues of string, established columns with data frame and made concat its own df

```
Client = pd.read_csv("CLZIPrevamp3.csv",encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
Client = Client[["clnum","concat"]]
clientzip = Client['concat']
```

CSV Examples

```
client  number  client add
40008               All, EdNULLNULLNULLNULLNULL
40009               EC, Inc. 4200 Exec-ParkwayS, MO  63141Attn: John Smith
40010               AWBWA, Inc. 2200 Northhighschool,VA  21801-7824Attn:              TerryLongNULL NULL
```

Example purposes

Zip Codes will also match international Zip codes, 4 digit and 5 digit zip codes and all fields do not have zip codes

I would then want to rewrite the results back into my Client dataframe as a third column for matching answers

Comment: Can you give a [mcve] without this spreadsheet / CSV that we cannot see?

Comment: I'm asking for you to [edit] your question with a sample of the CSV file, please

Comment: Unfortunately I can't give out any of the data, but the sample would be a single field.      "lastname - first name - city-state-zip-county .... all of this data is concatenated in one field

Comment: Then give an *example of the data*. Make it up. Otherwise, it's really hard to give you an answer

Comment: That is not a CSV.  If the zipcode is always the last 5 characters, just read a line and use `line[-5:]` to extract the last 5 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Is the ZIP always a US zip code? 5 digits at the end of a field?

Then slice it off.

```
>>> 'smithjonllcRichmondVa23220'[-5:]
'23220'
```

If you have 4 digits, then you might want the regex

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('\d{4,5}$', 'smithjonllcRichmondVa3220')[0]
'3220'
```

For "long zip codes" like `21801-7824`, it gets more complex, and it is situations when you are handed a CSV file when the columns themselves contain commas (see example)

> `AWBWA, Inc. 2200 Northhighschool,VA`

that you need to just ask for a different data format because good luck parsing that.

As far as pandas is concerned, you can `apply()` a function over a column.

Comment: Yeah pretty terrible, what if I grab the data in 6 columns, but there will still be commas in the text. I am directly querying out of our database. None of the fields really have the same order, so it is a complete mess

Comment: if you have a SQL database, the pandas has a `read_sql` function that you can query it directly in the column order you want. If the fields are out of order, then the insertion process to the database is bad.

Comment: insertion process of the database has no uniform way of input. IE: Virginia, VIRGINIA, VA,va,Va.,

Comment: You care about ZIP codes, not the state. There should ideally be a tuple of columns for `(state_name, state_abbrev, address, zip)`, or some alternative to that. It's the client's code to conform to the database, not the database to check for input validation.

Comment: you are completely right, but unfortunately the intake department makes mistakes and the database does not require them to enter everything in the right columns. Sometimes everything goes into the address column instead of the state,country,zip columns. We do not have any heavy data intelligence, and I was trying to solve a problem for them by helping them edit those fields

Comment: In that case, it's almost next to impossible. A regex means "regular expression", which operates over a "regular", meaning "well-defined", input. If the fields are out of order, you're screwed, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide 2 examples.

To be honest, if your CSV is consistently formatted in the way you mentioned in your example you can find the zipcodes using a simple albeit finite regex like this (It captures all non-space characters before the string "Attn" which seems to be a theme in your read string):

```
>>> def zipcodes():
            import re
            csv = '''client  number  client add
            40008               All, EdNULLNULLNULLNULLNULL
            40009               EC, Inc. 4200 Exec-ParkwayS, MO  63141Attn: John Smith
            40010               AWBWA, Inc. 2200 Northhighschool,VA  21801-7824Attn:                  TerryLongNULL NULL'''
            zips = re.findall('([\S]+)Attn', csv)
            print(zips)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
>>> zipcodes()
['63141', '21801-7824']
```

...

...

Now if you want something slightly better, which discriminates by ignoring numbers that start a new line you can use a lookahead example like so (NOTE: Python's lookahead documentation is not the best... sheesh). What the lookahead below says is 'capture a string of digits in the range of 5 to 6, with 0 or 1 dahses beween them if applicable, potentially followed by any number of digits (in this case 0 or more than 0) but only capture these numbers if they are not preceded by a newline character'

```
>>> def zipcodes():
            import re
            csv = '''client  number  client add
            40008               All, EdNULLNULLNULLNULLNULL
            40009               EC, Inc. 4200 Exec-ParkwayS, MO  63141Attn: John Smith
            40010               AWBWA, Inc. 2200 Northhighschool,VA  21801-7824Attn:              TerryLongNULL NULL'''
                zips = re.findall('(?<!\n)[\d]{5,6}[\-]?[\d]*', csv)
                print(zips)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
>>> zipcodes()
['63141', '21801-7824']
```

Hope this helps.